# Show / hide nested checkbox labels

Tags: jquery, checkbox, nested, label, show

I'm trying to make a nested label/checkbox visible when its containing label/checkbox is checked. I can't figure out how to target the specific nested label or if this is even the right way to do it.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/tfKva/15/

Here's the javascript:

```
$(".label-1").click(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $(this).next('.label-2').show(); // can't figure out how to get at the second "nested" label

        } else {
            $(this).next('.label-2').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `.show()` doesnt display element in `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: Also for your JSFiddle, you didn't include jQuery which means pretty much nothing would work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts on this:

- Your html could be a little better structured by not nesting multiple controls inside of a label (this will cause issues if you use the html `for` attribute properly).
- Sometimes it is easier to read css classes than use inline styles (what `hide()` and `show()` actually do)

That in mind, I would suggest the following. **JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/SaHGs/

**HTML**

```
<div class="check-container">
  <label for="label1">This is label 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="label1" class="hideshow" />

  <div class="autohide checkhidden">
    <label for="label2">This is label 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="label2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
  $(".hideshow").click(function(args) {
    var showStuff = $(this).prop("checked");
    $(this).parent().find(".autohide").each(function () {
      if (showStuff)
        $(this).removeClass("checkhidden");
      else
        $(this).addClass("checkhidden");
    });
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul { list-style:none; }
li {margin-bottom:20px; }

.check-container {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background: #e8e8e8;
}

.checkhidden { display: none; }
```

Hope that helps!

**Edit**

In order to check & uncheck the first item in the container just add the following two functions to your javascript:

```
$(".check-container").click(function () {
    var el = $(this).find("input:first");
    el.prop("checked", !el.prop("checked")).change();
});

$("input, label").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This is excellent... the only thing in my case is that the label (the gray box) needs to be the click handler...

Comment: @KirkRoss Very similar, but you might be looking for this, then: http://jsfiddle.net/hk7v7/2/ (added a stop propegation on click to make sure the container didn't hide and show when subfields were changed)

Comment: This is SO close! :) Now, how do you make Label 2 clickable to check/uncheck checkbox 2. Right now clicking label 2 triggers uncheck of checkbox 1, presumably because it's underneath?

Comment: @KirkRoss That is what the `preventPropegation` call does. Try out the latest version here and I think it works: http://jsfiddle.net/hk7v7/3/

Comment: Perfecto! Thank you so very very much... I will study this intensely.

Answer (score 1):

`.show()` doesn't display element if you have used `visibility:hidden;`

I will suggest you to use

```
  style="display:none;"
```

instead of

```
 style="visibility:hidden;"
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tfKva/16/)

Comment: This does solve my original issue so thank you kindly for your answer. I marked the next one as the answer because it deals with my sloppy HTML too.